# Powering 2.5" HDD via SATA but transfer data using USB?

Tags: power-supply, sata, sata-to-usb

My Mini ITX Motherboard only has 4 SATA ports, so I have ordered some USB header to USB female converters. When they arrive I will have 4 USB 2.0' s inside my case. I know that USB 2.0 will not be nearly as fast as SATA, but that doesn't really matter. What I need is a way so that I can power the HDD's via my power supply and have a SATA to USB male converter for data only.

The only thing I have right now is 2 of these

[image: these]

which require 2 USB's per HDD, since the power is also drawn via USB. Does a SATA Data Female to USB Data Male adapter even exist? I haven' t been able to find them anywhere.

Comment: How many HDDs do you need to connect? Is it prohibitive for you to sacrifice 2 USB ports per HDD?

Comment: Dmitry Grigoryev, 2 HDD' s, but I would also like to connect my Bluetooth adapter into it, so that would mean I am 1 port short.

Comment: Why not just buy a [PCIe-1x SATA controller](http://www.startech.com/ca/Cards-Adapters/HDD-Controllers/SATA-Cards/2-Port-PCI-Express-Internal-SATA-Controller-Card~PEXSATA22I)?

Comment: Well, some HDD would work while powered by a single USB port, especially if you don't go for the fastest ones. @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 is right though, if you can get SATA directly it will be faster and more stable.

Comment: *"Does a SATA Data Female to USB Data Male adapter even exist?"* -- Yes. The adapter you have is meant only for a 2.5" drive, and not a 3.5" or 5.25" drive.  I have a USB adapter for **IDE** and **SATA** drive interfaces (for data and control), and it requires an additional connection for powering the drive.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I simply dosen' t have room for it, as I mentioned in my post, it is a Mini-ITX board, I simply dont have the space for it.

Comment: @Sawdust the HDD' s I want inside are 2.5" anyway, so the only thing I need is a cable that inserts in the HDD as a normal SATA DATA cabel, but end out in a USB.

Comment: *"the HDD' s I want inside are 2.5" anyway"*  So what?  2.5", 3.5" and 5.25" SATA drives all use the same SATA interface connector. So the USB-to-IDEor-SATA adapter would still work in your situation, since it has no power connection..  Why do you resist a solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

USB-to-SATA adapters without the power connector do exist.  However they are most likely to also include IDE/PATA interfaces for versatilitty.[image]
The adapter above does support SATA, but does requires a SATA cable to connect the USB adapter to the SATA drive.